# Atomic domain that doesn't satisfy ACCP

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, factoring

I recently just completed an exercise which states an atomic domain $A$ is a UFD $\iff$ it satisfies the ascending chain condition on principal ideals.
This is all well and good, but because this is an if and only if statement, that seems to suggest there are atomic domains that DON'T satisfy the ACCP. Does anyone know of such an example? I would imagine you need something like the algebraic numbers but I am unsure.

Comment: I seem to remember something of this in Halmos's Boolean algebra book.  You may want to study up on boolean algebras.  It seems relevant; I'm shooting from the hip here though.

Comment: What is your definition of atomic domain?  You don't seem to be using the standard definition (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_domain).

Comment: I did think about that, but the problem with Boolean Algebras is that is isn't a domain! Every element is nilpotent--but there is a notion of "factorization" as the prime ideals (at least for finite Boolean rings) is a product (intersection)

Comment: I mean given a commutative ring $A$, $A$ is atomic if very element can be written as a finite  product of irreducible elements.

Comment: What about $K[x_1,x_2,...]$? It's an atomic domain and UFD but doesn't satisfy ACC.

Comment: @Ab_Sh Isn't this Noetherian by Hilbert's basis theorem? (I am assuming here $K$ is a field)

Comment: Doesn't Hilbert basis theorem only apply to a finite number of in-determinants?

Comment: Oops sorry did not notice that...

Comment: $K$ is a field and $x_i \quad i\in \mathbb N$. So it's not noetheian: $(x_1)\subset (x_1,x_2)\subset ...$.

Comment: @ab_Sh, Hmm.. you might have poked a hole in my result.  Perhaps I need A to be a PID.

Comment: Just want to make sure, this should be $A$ a UFD if and only if it satisfies the ascending chain condition _on principle ideals_ right?

Comment: Yes, I should have said ACCP. I will make the edit

Comment: Every Noetherian domain is an atomic domain but not every Noetherian domain is a UFD.  You seem to have gotten your statement mixed up somehow.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but I thought the two ingredients for  a UFD were the ACCP and a representation of every element as a product of irreducibles?

Comment: No, UFD additionally requires the representation as a product of irreducibles to be _unique_.

Comment: Yes, but I thought having the ACCP and representation of products of irreducibles gave you uniqueness?

Comment: Ah wait, my mistake, If you have ACCP and irreducible implies prime, then it is a UFD.

Answer (score 1):

An example of an atomic integral domain not satisfying the ACCP condition is constructed in Section 1 of the 1974 paper 
[Atomic rings and the ascending chain condition for principal ideals](https://dx.doi.org/10.1017%2Fs0305004100048532) by Anne Grams.

(Found via [Wikipedia:ACCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascending_chain_condition_on_principal_ideals).)

I haven't really tried to understand the details yet, so I'll leave it to someone else to explain how it works...